# How to use USB to I2C break-out module in Windows to communicate with I2C-slave

Tags: c, usb, i2c

I am using a the UMFT201XB-01 break-out board to communicate with an I2C slave. So far I installed the provided driver from FTDI. If I plug in the module, Windows Device Manager tells me that I can access it on COM8.

**Question 1**

I started coding a little programm to open the port, but I am getting the following error: "CreateFile failed with error 2". Indicating that the "file" (COM port) does not exist. Why?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
   HANDLE hCom;
   char comPort[] = "COM8";
   // Open a handle to the specified com port.
   hCom = CreateFile( comPort,
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                      0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
                      NULL,   //  default security attributes
                      OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
                      0,      //  not overlapped I/O
                      NULL ); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices

   if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
       // Handle the error.
       printf ("CreateFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
       return (1);
   }
}
```

**Question 2**

If I get the error fixed, how do I proceed from here? Are there any I2C-libraries for Windows I could use? Do I need to write my own I2C master program?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `“\\\\.\\COM8”` and `CreateFileA` function

Comment: https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/AN_255_USB-to-I2C-Example-using-the-FT232H-and-FT201X-devices.pdf

Comment: @gulpr `CreateFileA` function and the change in notation does not change the error message. The link is very usefull, thanks for that. As I understand, the FT201X cannot be used as a I2C slave?